# Why does Network.URI (parseURI) not like the pipe character?

Tags: url, haskell, uri

I'm using the `parseURI` function from the [network-uri package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri) to parse some urls. Some of these urls have a pipe character in and parsing fails for them. For example:

```
Network.URI> parseURI "http://something.com/foo|bar"
Nothing
```

However, these urls are obtained from a real website and they load correctly in a web browser, so there must be some sort of correct way of dealing with them.

Why does parsing fail on urls with a pipe character, and what can I do to make them correctly parse?

Comment: can you encode them (replace it with `%7C`) ?

Comment: I can yeah, and it correctly parses then. But fully url encoding the url results in `"http%3A%2F%2Fsomething.com%2Ffoo%7Cbar"`, which fails to parse too. So how do I choose which characters to url encode and which to not?

Comment: well I can only guess but usually you build up those from a base-url ("http://something.com/" I guess) - why do you both encode and then try to decode them (I guess you do the encoding in your front-end probably JS?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `escapeURIString` before parsing. `isUnescapedInURI` will tell you if the character is allowed unescaped in a URI component as mentioned in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri-2.6.1.0/docs/Network-URI.html#v:isUnescapedInURI).

```
λ> isUnescapedInURI '|'
False
```

So, to properly encode and parse it:

```
λ> parseURI $ escapeURIString isUnescapedInURI "http://something.com/foo|bar"
Just http://something.com/foo%7Cbar
```

In fact this specific corner case, is well explained in the Hackage docs.